# Can't resume from suspend on 16.04

Tags: suspend, acer, amd-graphics

The OS is working perfectly except that when I can't wake the system from suspend. The screen remains black and I need to do a hard restart.

I get this error message:

```
"Problem type: Kernel0ops
Title: Acer suspend/resume failure

This occurred during a previous suspend, and prevented the system form resuming property."
```

I have an Acer Aspire E5-521G with:

- 3.1 GiB RAM
- AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics x 4
- GalliumULLINS graphics (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
- 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04

How can I fix this?

Comment: Usted debe preguntar aquí http://www.ubuntu-es.org/forum#.V2giw2ZFxdY

Comment: Lo siento pero este sitio es solo en Ingles. Puedes utilizar herramientas como el [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com) si quieres, pero todo el contenido debe ser in Ingles. Si no lo hablas bastante bien como para entender las respuestas, mejor que busques un sitio de Ubuntu en Castellano.

Comment: Next time this happens write down the time. After a reboot you can inspect `/var/log/syslog` for entries relating to that time and include them in your question.